# Angular services wierdness

Tags: angular

So, i have this weird situation.

First off what works:

```
  "use strict";
  define([
    'mediastream/webrtc'
  ], function(WebRTC) {
    return ["api", function(api) {
      return new WebRTC(api);
    }];
  });
```

And calling with: `sourceDistribution.doCall(id);` works

But when i add login:

```
"use strict";
define([
  'mediastream/webrtc'
], function(WebRTC) {

  var Testi = function(api) {
    this.api = api;
    this.broadCastTypes = ["call", "video"];
  }

  Testi.prototype.initWebRTC = function(api) {
    return ["api", function(api) {
      return new WebRTC(api);
    }]; 
  }

  Testi.prototype.enterBroadcast = function(id) {
    console.log(1);
  }

  return ["api", function(api) {
    return new Testi(api);
  }]; 
});
```

And then call it by `sourceDistribution.initWebRTC(id).doCall(id);` I get error that can't call doCall from undefined.
Is this some angular specific i am not familiar with and how would one fix this issue.

P.S Adding text so stack overflow lets me post the question, i don't really know what is up with this.

Comment: Is this AngularJS or Angular2?

Comment: Found a monkey patch, will post answer when stack allows me to.